# Ignore missing methods in setter injection

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

I'm using PHP traits as mixins to inject optional services, i.e.

```
trait Logger
{
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function getLogger(): LoggerInterface
    {
        return $this->logger;
    }

    /**
     * Inject logger instance (called by the DI container)
     */
    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger): self
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then I use this trait in a class:

```
class UserService
{
    use Logger;
    /* ... */
}
```

Because this trait can be used in any class, I create a method injection call for all classes in `App\` namespace to inject the logger:

```
App\:
    # ...
    calls:
        - [setLogger, ['@monolog.logger']]
```

However, when Symfony encounters a service that doesn't implement `setLogger` method, it throws an error saying 'Invalid service: method "setLogger()" does not exist.'

Since this injection is supposed to be optional, is there a way to tell Symfony to ignore the call if the method does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are kinda reinventing the wheel with this one.

Symfony provides this functionality out of the box.

If a service implements `LoggerAwareInterface` ([link](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareTrait.php)), Symfony will automatically call `setLogger()` on the service to inject the logger service.

And since the same package also includes a `LoggerAwareTrait`, ([link](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareTrait.php)) you can simply do the following:

```
class FooService implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use LoggerAwareTrait;
}
```

And that's it. [If you are using the default autowire/autoconfigure settings](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging.html#using-a-logger-inside-a-service), no other configuration needed, and the logger will be automatically injected.

You can implement the above, remove your `calls: setLogger`from `services.yaml`, and the logger will be injected in the classes you want, are won't in the classes you don't.